# visualforce PDF - content overlapping with header

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I am trying to generate PDF from Visualforce but the problem I am running into is that content overlaps with Header.

Here is the image:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
    <apex:page controller="QuotePDFCustomController" showHeader="false" renderas="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page {
            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-left {
                content: element(footer);
            }

        }
        div.header {
            padding: 10px;
            position: running(header);
        }
        div.footer {
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            position: running(footer);
        }
        .pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
        }
        .pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="header">
    <img src='{!URLFOR($Resource.fake_logo)}' title="logo" width="200px"/>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" id="theGrid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" id="CompanyAddressId">
            <apex:outputText value="Company Address" id="theFirst"/>
            <apex:panelGroup id="theGroup">
                <apex:outputText value="{!$Organization.Street}" id="streetId"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!$Organization.City}" id="cityId"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!$Organization.State}" id="stateId"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!$Organization.PostalCode}" id="postalCodeId"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!$Organization.Country}" id="countryId"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>  
        </apex:panelGrid>
</div>
```

Comment: The Flying Saucer documentation for [How to I add a custom header or footer to my PDF?](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_40) says they support [margin boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-boxes) and [running elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-gcpm-20070504/#running1), However, my understanding was that the version used by Salesforce only supported CSS 2.1. That might explain whey they aren't having any affect.

Comment: Then again, the Knowledge article - [Adding page header/footer into a VisualForce page rendered as PDF](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US) uses them in the resolution.

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from that link but why is ot not working for me? and looks like many people are generating quote pdf from visualforce page successfully.

Comment: I just tried the example resolution code from the knowledge article. It didn't work for me. The divs all just rendered one after the other. The footer certainly didn't move to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my modified version of the Visualforce page from [Adding page header/footer into a VisualForce page rendered as PDF](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003705&language=en_US).

As you have done, I've added applyBodyTag="false" to the apex:page element to get the header/footer to render correctly.

I think the issue is that flying saucer isn't considering the height of the header content when positioning the content. At least with respect to an image in the header.

I found the easiest solution was to put some padding on the top of the page so that it would clear the header.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false"  >
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page {
                padding-top: 40px;
                @top-center {
                    content: element(header);
                }
                @bottom-left {
                    content: element(footer);
                }
            }
            div.header {
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: red;
                position: running(header);
            }
            div.footer {
                display: block;
                padding: 5px;
                position: running(footer);
            }
            .pagenumber:before {
                content: counter(page);
            }
            .pagecount:before {
                content: counter(pages);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <div class="header">
        <img src='https://na5.salesforce.com/img/seasonLogos/2015_summer.png' title="logo" width="173px" height="65px" />
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Actual page body information.</p>
        <div style="page-break-after: always"/>
        <p>Page Body content for the second page</p>
    </div>

</apex:page>
```

It renders as:

[image: Visualforce PDF header with padding to clear image]

Comment: Yes, I already added both the tags applyBodyTag and applyHtmlTag to False.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll have a quick go with an image in the header. Maybe you need to specify the Height of the image?

Comment: Ok. Thanks daniel, I will check this once I reach home. Thank you so much for your time and looking into this.

Comment: @javanoob It seems like flying saucer either isn't taking into account the height of the image in the header or doesn't care about the header size. I've just padded the content down to clear it.

Comment: Daniel, When I add height property to the header it is working only on the first page and second page onwards it is overlapping with the content. Can you try your example making it flow into the second page when you get chance? Thanks so much!

Comment: @javanoob Plan B (or is it C by now...) Add the required padding to the `@page`. That way it will be repeated on each subsequent page as well.

Comment: You are awesome! It worked excellent. Thanks a ton! I will keep posting questions until my quote pdf is in right format :) Please look into my questions.

Comment: `@page { padding-top: 40px; }` was crucial.  Thanks for the answer!